# Partition sum for $SO(N)$ one-dimensional lattice model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, lattice-model, partition-function

I'm looking for derivation of explicit form of partition function for $SO(N)$ one-dimensional lattice model. The initial expression is
$$
Z = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\sigma_{1}...d\sigma_{N}\text{exp}\left[-\beta\sum_{x = 1}^{L}\sum_{k = 1}^{N}\sigma_{k}(x)\sigma_{k}(x+1)\right]\delta(1-\sum_{k}\sigma_{k}^{2})
$$
I've heard that it is possible to obtain explicit expression for this sum, but don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done as an application of the transfer ``matrix'' method. You can, for example,  find an explicit computation for the XY model (N=2) in the book [The theory of magnetism II: Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics](https://books.google.ch/books?id=aqLvCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR3&ots=gG64CvjuHI&dq=The%20theory%20of%20magnetism%20II%3A%20Thermodynamics%20and%20Statistical%20Mechanics&hl=fr&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q=The%20theory%20of%20magnetism%20II:%20Thermodynamics%20and%20Statistical%20Mechanics&f=false) by Daniel Mattis (p. 75 *ff.*). Another reference, in which the general case is treated, is Section 9.2 in the book [Elements of Phase Transitions and Critical Phenomena](https://books.google.ch/books?id=qiEUDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA213&ots=0PUDMgmgJl&dq=classical%20heisenberg%20one-dimensional%20bessel&hl=fr&pg=PA211#v=onepage&q=classical%20heisenberg%20one-dimensional%20bessel&f=false) by Nishimori and Ortiz. The result is (well, you should replace $\beta$ by $-\beta$ in your case, since you seem to be interested in the antiferromagnetic case
):
$$
Z_L^{\mathrm{free}} = \Bigl\{\bigl(\tfrac\beta2\bigr)^{1-N/2}I_{\tfrac N2-1}(\beta)\Bigr\}^{L-1}\,,
$$
where $I_{N/2-1}$ is the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1_.2C_K.CE.B1).

---

Let me illustrate an alternative approach in the case of the XY model. In that case, writing the spins $\sigma_i=(\cos\theta_i,\sin\theta_i)$, the partition function with free boundary condition can be written
$$
Z_L^{\rm free} = (2\pi)^{-L}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]^L} 
\mathrm{d}\theta_1\cdots\mathrm{d}\theta_L 
\prod_{i=1}^{L-1} e^{-\beta\cos(\theta_{i+1}-\theta_i)}\,.
$$
Now, making the change of variables $\tau_i=\theta_{i+1}-\theta_i$ (say, with the additional variable $\tau_L=\theta_L$), the 
integrand factorizes and we get
$$
Z_L^{\rm free} = \Bigl\{
\tfrac1{2\pi}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} \mathrm{d}\tau\, e^{-\beta\cos\tau}
\Bigr\}^{L-1}\,.
$$
Now, you need to remember the definition of the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1_.2C_K.CE.B1):
$$
I_0(x) = \tfrac1{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{x\cos t} \mathrm{d} t\,.
$$
The conclusion is
$$
Z_L^{\rm free} = \bigl( I_0(-\beta) \bigr)^{L-1}\,.
$$
(Of course, you should check the above computation, I might have made some mistakes.)

Comment: Thank You! Yes, the sign is minus. But usually I see the series over the Bessel function. For example, for $O(N )$ model it is
$$
Z_{N} = \sum_{l = 0}^{\infty}\frac{N+2l-2}{l!}\frac{\Gamma(N+l-2)}{\Gamma (N-1)}\times b_{l}^{N-1},
$$
where
$$
b_{l} = \Gamma \left( \frac{N}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{\beta}\right)^{\frac{N}{2}-1}I_{l+\frac{N}{2}-1}(\beta)
$$
Why there is only $I_{0}$?

Comment: And how about delta-function?

Comment: Well, your delta function is just to force the spin to have norm $1$, which is automatic in my computation in terms of the angles. Concerning your first question, I don't know. Where did you read that? The solution I give above coincides with the one in the reference by Mattis I mentioned (obtained using the transfer matrix method), up to an irrelevant constant (he chooses a different high temperature limit), so it seems to be correct.

Comment: I know that this result (from my comment) is for $O(N)$ (my professor told me). I'm surprised that the diffeence is so huge.

Comment: I added an alternative reference and stated the general-$N$ result, which is established there (and coincides with the formula I derive for the $N=2$ case above). I also made my notations match yours (using $L$ for the number of spins and reserving $N$ to parametrize the dimension of the spins).

Comment: In your formula above, $N$ relates to the spin dimension, where is the size of the system ($L$)?

Comment: Spin group dimension.

Comment: Yes, but where is the dependence in $L$, the size of the system? Obviously, your partition function should depend on it.